# Can't login via SSH after restart

Tags: ssh

After I restart, everything from the A/V output works fine, and I can login locally, but until I do, I can't seem to login via SSH.  I can't get the connection to establish.  Is this something that happens by default?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure it's properly booted up? If it went to recovery mode (e.g. when being unable to mount removable drives via fstab) it's not accessible by ssh.

Answer (score 1):

Type

sudo raspi-config

Go to ssh and ensure its enabled. This should mostly do the trick.

Since you are have a spare monitor also go to terminal and type

ifconfig

So you can ensure that it actually has an active IP Address

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not something which happens by default.

I usually use my Pis headless without an attached keyboard or screen and login via ssh.  This is the default behaviour for the Raspbian systems I have installed.

If you have any further questions it would be useful to know if you are using a wired or wireless connection and details of the firmware version and operating system you are using.

Comment: It's the latest version of Raspian (looks like 3.18.7 from /proc/version).  The Pi is wired to a wireless bridge, and I was trying to access it via a wireless connection.  The strange thing is, I could swear I've done this numerous times before without having logged into the main terminal first.  Thanks for the clarification...sounds like it was a fluke or else there is a bug somewhere.